# Matching tags and string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string-matching

Is it possible to match a string and it's enclosing tags in jQuery?

I need to match the following…

```
<p>Oops! We could not locate your form.</p>
```

and replace it or add a class to it - I'm not sure yet. I know how to match the content or the tags but I need to target the whole thing specifically to replace it.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Like :contains? http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: You should really add a class or ID to the element, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Use `:contains`:

```
$('p:contains("Oops! We could not locate your form.")')
```

Or `filter`:

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Oops! We could not locate your form.';
});
```

The latter will be quicker, although neither are really ideal. If you need to find a common element in your HTML quite often, add a `class` or `id` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! you can do, first you need to assign any class or id to that `p` tag.